# How to execute lambda within a "closure scope"?

Tags: perl, lambda, closures, dynamic-scope

How this can work?

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    sub base {
      my $constant = "abcd";
      my ($driver_cr) = (@_);
      &$driver_cr;
    }

    base(sub {print $constant});
```

In other words how $driver_cr  can have an access to $constant without:

1. passing $constant as an arg to driver  `&$driver_cr($constant)`
2. changing scope of $constant to global `our $constant = "abcd";`
3. making a common block and moving $constant from base:

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   {
     my $constant = "abcd";
     sub base {
       my ($driver_cr) = (@_);
       &$driver_cr;
     }
     base(sub {print $constant});
   }
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work. It will die with "Global symbol "$constant" requires explicit package name"

Comment: right, so how to deal with it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why not pass `$constant` in as an argument?

Comment: because I have plenty of $constants (states) and driver (visitor) should just be able to kick in and do the job without passing everything by args.

Comment: @name, so just pass a single hashref containing everything.

Answer (score 4):

That's what function arguments are for.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub base {
  my $constant = "abcd";
  my ($driver_cr) = (@_);
  $driver_cr->($constant);
}

base(sub {
    my $constant = shift;
    print $constant;
});
```

But if you're really opposed to passing arguments, then:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Acme::Lexical::Thief;

sub base {
  my $constant = "abcd";
  my ($driver_cr) = (@_);
  &$driver_cr;
}

base(sub {
    steal $constant;
    print $constant;
});
```

Comment: What are other options besides 1,2,3?

Comment: thanks for that, I haven't seen that before. That said I was hoping for something similiar to c++x11.